# JSON:How to handle JSON response like this?

Tags: android, json

Here is the Response
I wonder how can I handle a JSON Response like this?
This a JSONArray, but didn't have a name
Here is the response:

```
[[84,"sinat","qq357068756@163.com"],[88,"msn","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[89,"163t","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[90,"mail","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[93,"mail","qq357068756@163.com"]]
```

Comment: `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("[[..]]");
for(int i; i < arr.length(); i++){JSONArray inner = arr.getJSONArray(i); inner.getInt(0); inner.getString(1); inner.getString(2); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data are not `JSONObject` but `JSONArray` !

```
String json_value = '[[84,"sinat","qq357068756@163.com"],[88,"msn","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[89,"163t","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[90,"mail","qq357068756@hotmail.com"],[93,"mail","qq357068756@163.com"]]';

JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_value);
```

and walk through it like

```
for(int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++){
    Log.d("Current index: "+i,"Current value: "+json_array.getJSONArray(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It's a JSONArray, I missed that, thanks for your suggenstion. I'm trying your method:)

Comment: Hello, I wonder how can I get the detail info like "sinat"? Does it still a JSONArray?

Comment: no, you can get detail like `json_array.getJSONArray(i).getString(1)`